# Solving an equation containing a Factorial

Tags: equation-solving

I have a question regarding the code to solve a particular equation. This is the equation:

```
364! / [(365-n)! * 365^(n-1)] <= 0.5
```

and I need to solve for `n`.

The code I used is:

```
Clear[n];
Solve[364!/{(365-n)! 365^(n-1)} <= 0.5, n]
```

However, it's not solving for `n` and only expanding `364!` with the rest of the equation as it is. Can anyone point out if I'm making a mistake in the code?

Comment: You are using `{}` and `[]` parenteses, where  you need `()`

Comment: The solution set is infinite...  but give `Solve[364!/((365 - n)! 365^(n - 1)) <= 1/2 && 
  0 <= n <= 365, n, Integers]` a spin, and `ArgMin[{Abs[364!/((365 - n)! 365^(n - 1)) - 1/2], 
  0 <= n <= 365}, n, Integers]` might be more what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

For this ("birthday puzzle"), it just easy enough to visualize and "solve immediately" (i.e brute force), e.g.

```
f[n_] := N[364!/((365 - n)! 365^(n - 1))]
DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, 0, 30}, GridLines -> {None, {1/2}}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

n->23
or

```
TableForm[Table[{j, f[j]}, {j, 20, 25}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "f[n]"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: And now the probability that at least three people (in general m people) share a common birthday. ;-)

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~tracy/courses/math135A/UsefullCourseMaterial/birthday.pdf

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze tricky indeed :) hyperlink above

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: Trivial, just a multinomial... or do you mean the reverse problem (number to have >=.5 p)?

Comment: @ciao yes the joy of multinomials...too busy lately...hoping for clear air to play but nothing on horizon...:)

Comment: @ ubpdqn Many thanks for the link which shows that there are several surprises in the "trivial" multinomial. As a physicist I like to view the birthday problem in terms of filling boxes at random and looking for occupation number patterns (just as Planck once did).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    FindRoot[364!/((365 - n)!*365^(n - 1)) == 0.5, {n, 25}]

(*  {n -> 22.7677}   *)
```

Have fun!